# Output of mlx90614 to mcufriend tft/lcd, not getting displayed

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, tft

Newbie here !! Im trying to display the output of my MLX90614 sensor on mcufriend tft display (with arduino UNO). But unable to do so. I can only see the TFT being lit to white color, text -> "Target" flashes on screen for millisecond and then again white lit screen.

1. But I tried tft-lcd sample codes, which are working fine &
2. I also tried mlx90614 (mlxtext code), which is also working fine.

But I combined the two codes so as to output it on TFT, which doesnt work. Hence I think this code might have some issue.
Im a beginner pls help!!

```
#include <Adafruit_TFTLCD.h> 
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>    
#include <TouchScreen.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_MLX90614.h>

#define LCD_CS A3 
#define LCD_CD A2 
#define LCD_WR A1 
#define LCD_RD A0 
#define LCD_RESET A4 

#define BLACK   0x0000
#define YELLOW  0xFFE0
#define WHITE   0xFFFF

Adafruit_TFTLCD tft(LCD_CS, LCD_CD, LCD_WR, LCD_RD, LCD_RESET);
Adafruit_MLX90614 mlx = Adafruit_MLX90614();

boolean buttonEnabled = true;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  mlx.begin();
  tft.reset();
  uint16_t identifier = tft.readID();
  tft.begin(identifier);
  tft.setRotation(1);
  tft.fillScreen(WHITE);
  tft.drawRect(0,0,319,240,YELLOW);

}

void loop() {

  tft.setCursor(0,1);
  tft.setTextSize(2);
  tft.print("Target  ");
  tft.setTextColor(BLACK);
  tft.print(mlx.readObjectTempC());
  tft.print(" C");
  Serial.print("*C\tObject = "); Serial.print(mlx.readObjectTempC()); Serial.println("*C");
  Serial.println();
  delay(500);

}
```

Comment: look at `#define LCD_CS A3` ... do you see it conflicting with another define? ... look for other conflicts

Comment: @jsotola, deleted all the unnecessary defines, still not working

Comment: start with working tft code ... add a couple lines of mlx code an test ... repeat until failure

Comment: The Adafruit library `Adafruit_MLX90614` already includes the wire library in the `.h` file and the constructor calls `wire.begin` in the `.cpp` file. Please try removing the wire library you've included in your sketch. If that doesn't solve the problem, follow jsotola's suggestion and add 1 line of code at a time to the working example until it "breaks".